# Flow Decision Element does not support recordtypeid?

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

I am trying to access recordtypeid from Account record in a before context flow.The flow is not entering the insert condition criteria. After debugging i came to know that recordtypeid is causing the issue.
[![Record.reocrdtypeid in Decision element][1]][1]

I have first removed 4th condition i.e recordtypeid it was working fine the insert criteria passed but after i add the recordtypeid it is returning false. I have tried with developername as well.

Its a record triggered flow which fires before create & update optimize for fast field updates.

Comment: Can you please help to add the error snapshot in `flow-debug mode` to understand the issue further more better?

Comment: is your custom label value a 15 char or 18 char ID?

Comment: 18 character ID

Answer (score 1):

It's the "optimize for fast field updates" that's causing the issue here. That precludes lookup references in both actions *and* conditions (at least as of API version 57), and record types are a kind of lookup. Switch to the other optimization mode and this issue should disappear.

Comment: for both create and update ?

Comment: I believe so, though it's been a bit since I ran into this particular issue. It's not a matter of whether you're creating a new record or not, it's a matter of whether you're referencing any *other* records (e.g., by lookup).

Comment: But i need to run this flow in before context.

Comment: Since i am modifying the field on account it needs to happen in before context.

Comment: Then you're going to need to find some other non-lookup field to filter on, here unfortunately. (Formula fields don't work either, I've tried)

Comment: And FYI it is not working even in other optimise flow..